# Issues with PowerShell and VSCODE

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I've not had any problems running PS within VSCODE but of recent (within the last week) i seem to be getting weird behaviour where when debug / running a script it doesn't run the current version of the script.

For example, if i comment out a line in the script, save it, hit run, it runs but with the line uncommented. I stop the script, save again, close the script, go back in and open the script again and it runs with the line commented out.

Version: 1.54.1 (user setup)
Commit: f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8
Date: 2021-03-04T22:38:31.419Z
Electron: 11.3.0
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

Comment: It sounds like the line you are commenting out is a line where you are assigning a value or object to a variable.  Since the session has run once that variable has been assigned already.  If you want to rerun it in the same session you should set the variable to $null after using it.

Alternatively if you click the Bin icon to kill the current session it will ask you to restart the session and it will be fresh for you without having to completely close and reopen VSCode.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The line isnt a variable it’s a line that calls another function. The function gets info from various sources and my script then uses that data assigned to arrays / variables. When I’m testing script functionality i just comment out the line that calls the function to use data already stored as it can take some time to run. 

But as mentioned it seems to ignore the fact I’ve commented the line abs I need Tomclose the file and go back in.

Comment: Is that function assigning data to a variable that could be persisting though?  

Does the problem persist if you kill the session within VSCODE rather than doing the restart?